# He looks younger than his age

Tags: phrase-requests

He looks younger than his age.

How does one say a guy looks younger than his actual age?

Comment: You could say he is a **youthful** fifty or whatever age he actually is.

Comment: @Matt I think this should say "How does one say" not "How can one say..." Using *can* could imply incredulity that such a thing is possible; *does* simply asks the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I only edited the tag. Feel free to edit the body :)

Comment: @Matt and Eric: Sorry, misread the edit history. I've altered it.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can say, "you don't look your age".

Comment: you can also say you age well or you have aged well ,but it doesn't mean the same thing .

Comment: This could also be taken the other way... in that you look much older than your age.

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily mean one looks *younger* than they really are, but a grown man with a very youthful appearance is sometimes said to have a *baby face*. (My wife used to say this about Paul McCartney for instance).

Comment: Baby face = fat face

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd But in a cute way, like a baby. (That is, I never heard my wife say that Meatloaf had a baby-face...)

Comment: Maybe... I am not sure many guys in their 30s-50s would be happy to be described with a baby face.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I never asked Paul :P Then again, not all men like to look younger than their age (until they are or look really ancient)... men are weird in that way. Just in that one way.

Comment: Looks like we all got mass downvoted and then a really poor answer was accepted.

Comment: So indeed, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You look young for your age - or You don't look your age - as was already said above.

Answer (score 1):

This exemplifies a famous ambiguity in philosophy and semantics.
The sentence

- *Bill thinks he's younger than he is.*

is a perfectly ordinary, almost idiomatic sentence, but it is actually ambiguous between two senses,
one of which is contradictory (and requires effort to see, because of that).
The other, non-contradictory, sense is the normal interpretation.

*Bill thinks he's younger than he is* can mean **either**

- *[Bill thinks [that Bill is `X` age]] and [Bill is `Y` age], where `X < Y`* (normal sense)
  **or**
- *Bill thinks [Bill's age `X` is less than Bill's age `X`]*  (contradictory sense: `X < X`)

People normally have to have the contradiction pointed out to them; it's inherent in the structure of the comparative. But it's contradictory, so we ignore that meaning and go for the more likely one.
"Likely", anyway, in human perceptual terms. Computers don't perceive that way, so this has
been tripped over pretty frequently in parsing and extraction technology.

Answer (score 0):

He is suffering from **agerasia**.

> youthful appearance in an old person

Another antiquated word is **neanimorphism**.

> Looking younger than one actually is

Something that I would actually say in a conversation - **well-preserved**, **boy/girl-ish good looks**, or **surprisingly youthful**.

> well-preserved - used for saying that someone looks younger than they
>   are

Answer (score 0):

> You look younger than [**you are**](http://youqueen.com/beauty/how-to-look-younger-than-you-are/).
>
> Did you discover the fountain of youth (or what)?
>
> You still have young looks for your age.

Answer (score 0):

**[Neanimorphic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/neanimorphic)**: looking younger than one's years

Or

If someone is older, and we are aware of their chronological age, it is often said '**they have aged well**'. Celebrities are often on lists that refer to them as 'aging well'.

Answer (score 0):

Also , **you have a youthful appearance** or more formal **a juvenile aspect**

Answer (score 0):

> - He has good genes.
> - Good genes run in the family

Typically when someone's appearance belies their real age, many will attribute the smooth skin, thick glossy hair and a lean body to their genetic makeup.

> When the “Guess Your Age” guy at the West Virginia State Fair guessed
>   he was 37, Jim had to whip out his driver’s license to prove he was
>   really 55. “Man, you look good,” the carnie said.
>
> I have always assumed that my husband [benefits from especially good
>   genes](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/health-science/health-and-fitness-habits-can-help-people-keep-their-youthful-good-looks/2011/07/20/gIQAByZ7nI_story.html). But now that Jim is in his 60s, people aren’t just shocked to
>   learn his age, they also want to know how he does it.

Answer (score 0):

Baby face

noun
1. a face having a bland babyish or childish appearance, especially a plump, small-featured face unmarked by characteristic lines.
2. a person having such a face.